# How To Insert images into 1 table and other Data in another Table Using last insert id from 1 form in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-insert, last-insert-id

**this my whole Code And To Insert images into 1 table and other Data in another Table Using last insert id 1 form in Codeigniter **

Create.php (

This is View File)

```html
<?= form_open('Packages/save') ?>
<label>Package Name:</label><?= form_input('name') ?><br>
<label>Package Name:</label><?= form_input('price') ?><br>
<label>Descriptione:</label><?= form_textarea('description') ?><br>
<label>Image 1:</label><?= form_upload('image1') ?><br>
<label>Image 2:</label><?= form_upload('image2') ?><br>
<label>Image 3:</label><?= form_upload('image3') ?><br>
<?= form_submit('', 'Create Package')?>
<?= form_close()?>
```

Packages.php (This is Controller)

```html
function save()
{
    $this->package->create($this->input->post());
    redirect('packages/');

}
function image_upload(){
    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => "/Images/",
        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
    );
    $lst_id=$this->package->create($this->input->post());
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $image_data = array(
            'id'=> $lst_id,
            'upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('upload_success',$image_data);
    }
    $this->package->create($this->input->post());
}
```

Package.php (this is model)

```html
function create($post)
{
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $post);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
function upload($image_data){
    $this->db->insert('images', $image_data);
}
```

Comment: is the code correct??

Comment: Error is 
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'image1' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `packages` (`name`, `price`, `description`, `image1`, `image2`, `image3`) VALUES ('sdfgg', '12', 'asdasdas', 'images.jpg', 'images (1).jpg', 'images (1).jpg')

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Trips\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 329

Comment: no response????

Comment: My table structure for images is simple just 3 images fields and 1 id and field

Comment: if you can edit the code and fix the errors please?

Comment: simple...
just Package name , price,description